# No such file or directory while trying to give permissions to Tomcat

Tags: permissions, tomcat

I made /opt/tomcat directory for Apache Tomcat and extracted latest binary distribution to it. I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04) article and everything besides this line works:

```
sudo chmod g+r conf/*
```

Whenever I try to do this I get following error:

```
chmod: cannot access 'conf/*': No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure can I just skip this step and leave it as it is (probably there aren't any files in it right now).